# My nested serializer is not showing proper details of foreign key

Tags: api, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to use nested serializer to show data of chargerbookmark as following:
[{

```
    "favouriteID": 1,
    "favouriteCustomer": 1
    "favouriteCharget":{
         chargerId:1,
         chargerName:abc,
         chargerDetails:xyz
         }

}]
```

but i'm getting

```
[
    {
        "favouriteID": 1,
        "favouriteCustomer": 1
    }
]
```

here is ,my code:

models.py--

```
  class Charger(models.Model):
      def __str__(self):
          return self.chargerName 

      chargerId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      chargerName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      chargerDetails = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


  class Customers(models.Model):
      def __str__(self):
          return self.customerName

      customerId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      customerName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
      customerEmail = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  class FavouriteCharger(models.Model):
      def __str__(self):
          return str(self.favouriteCustomer)
   

      favouriteID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      favouriteCharger = models.ForeignKey(
          Charger, related_name='ChargerF', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      favouriteCustomer = models.ForeignKey(
          Customers,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py--

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

```
  class CustomerSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Customers
          fields = "__all__"


  class ChargeringStationSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Charger
          fields = "__all__"


  class BookmarkSerialiser(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      ChargerF = ChargeringStationSerialiser(read_only=True, many=True)

      class Meta:
          model = FavouriteCharger
          fields = ("favouriteID", "ChargerF",
              "favouriteCustomer")
```

views.py--

```
  class BookmarkList(generics.ListAPIView):
      queryset = FavouriteCharger.objects.all()
      serializer_class = BookmarkSerialiser
```

Please help, i'm new to api development and i'm not able to understand what's the issue

Comment: What happens when you replace `ChargerF` in your serializer with `favouriteCharger`?

Comment: yeah that worked, thanks